# Not able to launch Karma test: Uncaught Error: Module name "http" has not been loaded

Tags: angularjs, node.js, requirejs, karma-jasmine

I am getting this error while running the karma test

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "http" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
at C:/projects/xxx_Phase_II/xxx/xxx-web/src/test/javascript/config/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:140
```

It is rooted at `dev-rest-proxy.js` first line where it says

```
var http = require('http');
```

My `package.json` looks like this

```
{
"name": "myApp",
"description": "myApp Web UI",
"engines": {
"node": ">= 0.8.4"
},
"dependencies": {
"express": ">=3.x",
"karma": ">=0.13",
"request": ">=2.27.0"
},
"scripts": {
"pretest": "start node server.js",
"karma": "node ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start ./karma.unit.conf.js",
"test": "node ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start ./karma.e2e.conf.js"
},
"version": "0.1.0",
"devDependencies": {
  "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
  "jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
  "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
  "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.5",
 "dev-rest-proxy": "^0.3.0"
 }
}
```

My `karma.unit.config.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '../../../',

        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
        files: files: [
            'app/vendor/**/**/*.js'
        ]


        reporters: ['progress'],

        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
            suite: 'unit'
        },

        port: 9876,

        runnerPort: 9100,

        colors: true,

        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        autoWatch: true,

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        captureTimeout: 60000,

        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The pattern I gave in `files` was overbroad as it was including node server-side files like `dev-rest-proxy.js`. My `karma.unit.config.js` had:

```
        files: [
           'app/vendor/**/**/*.js'
        ],
```

So it would include this file:

```
app/vendor/node_modules/dev-rest-proxy/dev-rest-proxy.js
```

The `dev-rest-proxy` is backend node stuff and is not supposed to loaded on browser i.e it refers to code/module like 'http' which is purely a server side script.

The important clue which I missed was the error message itself:

```
Module name “http” has not been loaded
```

`http` is a node's server side module.